# How to launch jar the same way Jar Launcher does

Tags: memory, java

The source of this problem is that Jar Launcher (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Jar\ Launcher.app`) runs the jar just perfectly *(as far as I know, the Jar Launcher app is the one that runs jars which you double click in finder)*, but I need to set a memory buffer limits.

So I've tried to run the jar like:

```
java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -jar <path_to_jar>
```

And when I run a jar like this, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.minecraft.Util.excutePost(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Do you have any idea what can be wrong with me launching app the way described above? Can you suggest any way to launch the jar like the Jar Launcher does or how to specify memory buffer limits for Jar Launcher?

### EDIT

My console java version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

But I have no idea how to find out what version is Jar Launcher using

Comment: Programming question should be posted on Stackoverflow. I flag your question in this sense.

Comment: The reported error indicates something else is wrong - a bad minecraft library?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the thing is that when it's being run by double clicking everything works ok. And that's what I want to find out: how the jar is being run by double clicking and how it differs from the way I've launched it from terminal

Comment: @Ermiar the question is not about the exception but about how Jar Launcher app works. Are you sure that I should post it on stack overflow?

Comment: @Uko Oh okay, still I am not sure the question belong here because it involve programming. I let other people judge that by flagging or not your question as off topic.

Comment: Which java version are you using on the command line (`java -version`)? It might be that the Jar Launcher is using a different one.

Comment: @patrix `java version "1.6.0_33"`, but I have no idea how to find out what version is Jar Launcher using

Comment: /Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app, a screenshot could be helpful if several versions are displayed

Comment: Since Jar Launcher is something Apple delivers and people wanting to run java programs will need to know how to configure that tool, it's clearly on topic here. If the focus becomes how to modify the java code to work with Mac's limitations, then it starts to stray, but configuring or documenting a runtime tool is on topic here. That being said, if the OP wants to have it migrated to Stack Overflow or another site since programmers might be a better resource to know this part of Mac better - we would be open to that request by the author if the question doesn't get answers in a week's time...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to specify the class paths with the `cp` option to `java` and the library paths with the `D` option. The Minecraft launcher under `/Applications` handles this if you have a default install.  If you want to run the default configuration from the commandline, just run something like the following with the memory values of your choosing:

```
java -Xmx2048M -Xms512M -jar \
/Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/MinecraftLauncher.jar
```

Here's an example of how I run Minecraft from the command-line for ad-hoc mode.  I put the following in a script, name it and run it by name:

```
MCHOME="$HOME/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin"
CP="$MCHOME/minecraft.jar:$MCHOME/lwjgl.jar:$MCHOME/lwjgl_util.jar:$MCHOME/jinput.jar"

java -Xmx2048M -Xms512M -cp "$CP" \
    -Djava.library.path="$MCHOME/natives" \
    net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
```